# dbaTools fails to connect with Azure AD account on PowerShell Core

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-core, dbatools

Using **PowerShell Core 7.1.4**, when I try to connect to my MS SQL instance using integrated security with an **Azure AD account** with `Connect-DbaInstance` from the **dbatools** module, I am met with an error message about login failed using **NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON**. It works fine from PowerShell 5.1.

I am using an Azure AD connected account. The same account that I use to connect to MSSQL using SSMS. Client and server is on same domain (localhost). The command was executed from a local powershell core session - no remoting involved. SYSTEM account is not involved.

`Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance <servername>\<instancename>` results in:

> Error connecting to [<servername>\<instancename>]: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Connecting to the same MS SQL instance using **PowerShell 5.1** and **SSMS** works fine with the the same Azure AD account.

Is it not possible to use windows authentication from PowerShell Core to MS SQL?

Comment: Yes, it's not just possible, it's the default. What account are you using though? Are the client and server on different domains? How did you launch the command? Directly from a terminal or over a remote session? Was it launched as `SYSTEM` from a service? What's the actual command line? What's the actual, full error message?

Comment: I am using an Azure AD connected account. The same account that I use to connect to MSSQL using SSMS.
Client and server is on same domain (localhost).
The command was executed from a local powershell core session - no remoting involved. `SYSTEM` is not involved. 
`Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance <servername>\<instancename>` results in **Error connecting to [<servername>\<instancename>]: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'**.

Comment: When the client and server aren't in the same domain, the Windows account can't be used for authentication. When you run something using the `Service` or `Network` account the actual account used it the machine's, `‘DomainName\MachineName$’`. `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON` is used when there are Kerberos issues

Comment: `an Azure AD connected account` that's not exactly Windows authentication. It's almost certain there are Kerberos issues. [This blog post](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/06/13/sql-server-login-failed-for-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon/) explains how to look into SQL Server's Error log for the relevant log entries.

Comment: Please put all the relevant information in the question itself.

Comment: Have you tried any of the AAD examples in `Get-Help Connect-DbaInstance -Examples`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but I don't think the problem is AAD as I can connect using the same AAD account in PowerShell 5.1 and in SSMS.